# using php include function for classes

Tags: php, mysql, apache, include, directory

Trying to get a hang of classes in php, trying to include carClass.php into new_file.php.

carClass.php

```
     <?php
    class carClass

    {
        private $color;
        private $gear;
        private $model;
        private $gas;

        function paintCar($carColor) {
            $this->color = $carColor;
        }

        function findCarColor() {
            echo "$color";
        }

        function shiftGear($newGear) {
            $this->gear=$newGear;
        }

        function findGear() {
            echo "$gear";
        }

        function chooseModel($newModel) {
            $this->model = $newModel;
        }

        function findModel() {
            echo"$model";
        }

        function fillCar($gasAmount) {
            $this->gas = $gasAmount;
        }

        function lookAtGauge() {
            echo "$gas";        
        }

    }

?>
```

its just a bunch of getters and setters. Im trying to include this class to new_file.php

new_file.php

```
  <?php
     include("carClass.php");

    $car = new carClass;

    $car->chooseModel("Mustang");
    $car->paintCar("black");
    $car->shiftGear("5th");
    $car->fillCar("half");

    $car->findModel();
    $car->findCarColor();
    $car->findGear();
    $car->lookAtGuage();

?>
```

When I try to execute this file I get these error messages

Warning: include(carClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\testFile\new_file.php on line 4

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'carClass.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\testFile\new_file.php on line 4

Fatal error: Class 'carClass' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\testFile\new_file.php on line 6

I believe both files are in testFile directory so I'm not sure whats going on. I appreciate any help you guys can give me as usual.

Comment: how are you calling/executing new_file.php? Unless the php's current working directory is the same directory as `new_file.php` it will not look in there for `carClass.php`, you will need to use a relative path to the cwd, or use an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

The include path is set against the server configuration (PHP.ini) but the include path you specify is relative to that path so in your case the include path is (actual path in windows):

```
  <?php

   include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/carClass.php';

   $car = new carClass;

   $car->chooseModel("Mustang");
   $car->paintCar("black");
   $car->shiftGear("5th");
   $car->fillCar("half");

   $car->findModel();
   $car->findCarColor();
   $car->findGear();
   $car->lookAtGuage();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's auto loading feature which will automatically load a class when an object is created. If you have many classes then you can use it an header file so that you don't need to worry about using this include every time.

```
 <?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
    class carClass

    {
        private $color;
        private $gear;
        private $model;
        private $gas;

        function paintCar($carColor) {
            $this->color = $carColor;
        }

        function findCarColor() {
            echo $this->color;
        }

        function shiftGear($newGear) {
            $this->gear=$newGear;
        }

        function findGear() {
            echo $this->gear;
        }

        function chooseModel($newModel) {
            $this->model = $newModel;
        }

        function findModel() {
            echo $this->model;
        }

        function fillCar($gasAmount) {
            $this->gas = $gasAmount;
        }

        function lookAtGauge() {
            echo $this->gas;        
        }

    }

?>
//
  <?php
     include("carClass.php");

    $car = new carClass;

    $car->chooseModel("Mustang");
    $car->paintCar("black");
    $car->shiftGear("5th");
    $car->fillCar("half");

    $car->findModel();
    $car->findCarColor();
    $car->findGear();
    $car->lookAtGauge();

?>
```